# PyInstaller - OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: pyinstaller

I run into "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" while running pyinstaller. Could someone point me what needs to be installed or done to solve it?

Below is the error message.

```
root@mylinkit:/usr# pyinstaller t123.py
2999 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
3002 INFO: Python: 2.7.12
3013 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.18.44-mips-with-glibc2.0
3026 INFO: wrote /usr/t123.spec
3069 INFO: UPX is not available.
3089 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/usr', '/usr']
3092 INFO: checking Analysis
3258 INFO: checking PYZ
3346 INFO: checking PKG
3356 INFO: Bootloader /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit/run
3358 INFO: checking EXE
3360 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
3362 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
3575 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /usr/build/t123/t123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 411, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 563, in assemble
self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 486, in exec_command_all
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
root@mylinkit:/usr#
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some investigation and I believe `binutils` may be the missing dependency.

```
apt-get install binutils
```